# Program to test a SQL connection string?

Tags: sql

I need a free and quick to download program that can test a connection string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can make one yourself in 20sec. For example in C#
- Create a new WinForms application
- Create a new SqlConnection(connectionString)
- Exception => Bad connection string
- All ok => Good connection string

```
SqlConnection conn = null;

try {
  conn = new SqlConnection("connection string here");
  conn.Open();
  // Good connection string
} catch (SqlException sqlE) {
  // Bad connection string
} finally {
  if (conn != null) conn.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use conn.Close opposed to conn.Dispose ?

Comment: That's not necessary, almost all (if not all) objects that implement the iDisposable pattern automatically Release/Close/Quit/Shutdown any resources held by that object.

You might be familiar with the using-directive, it basically generates exactly the same code I wrote above.

Comment: Might as well make it a console app, rather than WinForms.  Also, depending on the connection string it might need to be a System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection rather than a SqlConnection.

Answer (score 2):

An abbreviated version of Xyphrax's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1497110/152648) (assuming you're running this in the debugger):

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection("Connection String Here"))
conn.Open();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a tinny Windows application tool: http://www.webpowersoftware.com/App/Tools/SqlServer/SqlServerConnectionTest.exe.

Comment: I guess that domain / link is not valid anymore...